# How to access Request Id that is shown in Bixby Simulator in Javascript Action

Tags: bixby

I would like to access the unique request id value which is shown in the simulator logs in the Javascript Action Method of Bixby. How can this be accomplished?

[image: Sample Request ID]

Comment: Curious to know your use case or how you plan to use this information.

Comment: I needed this information primarily for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754104/does-bixby-cache-the-requests-on-server, I didn't know we could disable caching. I was planning to send the request-id in the http request to make the new request unique and disable the caching.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad we covered that base. I'll update that question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754104/does-bixby-cache-the-requests-on-server) with additional information that will make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that information is available to the capsule. In JavaScript, you do have access to `vivContext.sessionID`, but I suspect that is not exactly the variable you're looking for.

For information, check here:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information

Comment: Request ID is for Samsung server logging and has nothing to do with http.getUrl() cache. NO action in capsule can use this Request ID in anyway.