# Does Bixby cache the requests on server?

Tags: bixby

In my application all the utterances from Bixby are redirected to an action which makes an api call. This api call returns the response to Bixby for the user utterance. Recently I observed that if the user says the following: -

**user says: -** *Add xyz to my cart*
**api response: -** *Would you like 2 of those?*
**user says: -** *Yes*
**api response: -** *Would you like to checkout?*
**user says: -** *Yes*

Ideally now the request should come to my api and the user should be shown the checkout result page, but instead Bixby shows the user cached response and is shown the below response again: -

**api response: -** *Would you like to checkout?*

and the loop continues indefinitely. I wanted to know if this behaviour is expected? Is there a way we can skip the caching and send the request to the api endpoint to respond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, requests are cached on the server. You can disable the cache if you wish.

For example,

```
let options = {
    cacheTime: 0
  };

let response = http.getUrl('https://my-capsule.com/api/search/', options);
```

See https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http#http-options for more options. No pun intended. :)

Comment: I've done exactly that (set ````cacheTime: 0```` in options), and I'm sending the options object with my ````http.postUrl()```` request. My endpoint is *still* not getting hit if I repeat the same command. This is an ````http.postUrl() ```` request. Any troubleshooting advice?

Comment: Yes. Note that the order of the positional arguments is different between getUrl and postUrl. There's an extra "params" argument for postUrl. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http#httpgeturlurl-options

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `cacheTime` provided by the client, the Server can sometimes provide additional directives (`max-age` and `no-store` or `no-cache`) in the `Cache-Control` header. When this occurs, this is what Bixby does:

1. `no-cache` or `no-store`:  Bixby will not cache anything. This will override the `cacheTime` variable provided by client.
2. time of response + `max-age` < current time:  Remove response from cache (even if client requested a longer `cacheTime`)
3. time of response + `cacheTime` < current time:  Remove response from cache (even if response provided a longer `max-age`)