# Transient result in Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to make a result transient in bixby.

Specify a text reply like so:

```
text (reply) {
  description (HomeAssistant conversation reply)
  features {
    transient
  }
}
```

However it seems as if the result is still cached, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, if you continue to have issues after you have explored Pete Haas' solution, please reach out to the support team via the Contact Support form (https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) or via Bixby Developer Studio as it will put you in touch with someone who can discuss your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks, the http cache solved the issue. Now my problem is that I cannot use my own capsule! Since I am in a country where third party capsules are not allowed yet. Do you know if there is any way to sideload a capsule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the data is being cached in your server side?  Here's a related question and answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754104/does-bixby-cache-the-requests-on-server).

Comment: This was precisely the issue! Thanks.